# Lambda / AWS simple storage options

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function that is fronted by an API gateway for access.

I need to store the last time this was executed so I can retrieve data from an external service since the last execution.

I had planned to use DynamoDB for this purpose.

Is this the simplest option for this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DynamoDB is a really good option for that. DynamoDB and AWS Lambda work really well together. I definitely recommend DynamoDB for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

With DynamoDB, you can create database tables that can store and retrieve any amount of data and serve any level of request traffic.For this case DynamoDB is the best option.